# Swift: block all code until a function finishes executing

Tags: swift, semaphore

I am calling a function that gets crucial data from serve. I want all code to wait until that happens. I tried using semaphore but it doesn't seem to work like expected. My code is like so:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    getUserById(userIDParam)
    thisShouldWait()
....

func getUserById(id: Int) -> Void {
    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    WebService.getUserById(id) { user in
        AppDelegate.CurrentUser = user
    }
}
```

the function: thisShouldWait() executes before the the completion handler finishes. So I tried using semaphore, but that ran indefinitely. What is the solution? my serverice getUserById:

```
class func getUserById(userID: Int, completionHandler: (User) -> Void) -> Void {

    let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0)
    let defaultSession = NSURLSession(configuration: NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration())

    let methodParameters = []

    let url = appDelegate.URL

    let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {
        } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 || httpResponse.statusCode <= 299 {
                let user: User = parseSearchResults(data)
                completionHandler(user)
            }
        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()

    dispatch_semaphore_wait(semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
}
```

Comment: Two things: (a) you are missing a `dispatch_semaphore_signal` in the completion handler to signal that everything is done. (b) you really sure you want to lock up the UI when wait for the result?

Comment: Don't, just don't. If you need to do something then use a splash screen and wait for the async result to trigger a segue, never block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `dispatch_semaphore_signal` in your completion handler:

```
let dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask = defaultSession.dataTaskWithURL(url) { data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
    } else if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        if httpResponse.statusCode >= 200 || httpResponse.statusCode <= 299 {
            let user: User = parseSearchResults(data)
            completionHandler(user)
        }
    }
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore) // Added
}
```

Make sure you call `getUserById` on a background thread. Locking up the UI when it's being done is never a good idea.